# TikZ with multi colum datas

Tags: pgfplots

I have a data file containing 3 columns, X, Y and Z.

```
   X               Y               Z
# datas from the natural movement of a robot
   0.0000000e+00   3.3891017e-01  -1.3249598e-01
   2.0000000e-02   3.3675858e-01  -1.3535520e-01
   4.0000000e-02   3.3470984e-01  -1.3826038e-01
   6.0000000e-02   3.3287897e-01  -1.4130291e-01
   8.0000000e-02   3.3136947e-01  -1.4456564e-01
```

I want a graph that can display Y(X) or Z(X). How can I do?

I tried

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{width=7cm}
        \begin{axis} [title= two curves]
            \addplot [blue, x=X, y=Y] table
                    {myfile.dat};
            \addplot [red, x=X, y=Z] table
                    {myfile.dat};
            \legend{$y(x)$,$z(x)$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But the output is always Y(X).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table options should go to `table` keyword and not to `\addplot` then it works

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[]{
   X               Y               Z
   0.0000000e+00   3.3891017e-01  -1.3249598e-01
   2.0000000e-02   3.3675858e-01  -1.3535520e-01
   4.0000000e-02   3.3470984e-01  -1.3826038e-01
   6.0000000e-02   3.3287897e-01  -1.4130291e-01
   8.0000000e-02   3.3136947e-01  -1.4456564e-01
}\mytable
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [width=7cm,title= two curves]
            \addplot[blue] table [x=X, y=Y] {\mytable};
            \addplot[red] table [x=X, y=Z] {\mytable};
            \legend{$y(x)$,$z(x)$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```